# Matplotlib imshow()'s default normalization vs custom implementation

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

The "norm" parameter's description in Matplotlib's [axes.imshow() documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html) says that by default "a linear scaling mapping the lowest value to 0 and the highest to 1 is used" for normalization.

This means that a function of the form: f(x) = (x - x_min)/(x_max - x_min) would map image value x to f(x) lying between 0 and 1. However, I cannot reproduce this behavior if I normalize the image myself and then display it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A = np.random.normal(size=(4,5,3))
# A does have negative values
print(np.min(A), np.max(A))

# normalizing to range [0,1]
B = (A - np.min(A))/np.ptp(A)

figure = plt.figure()
ax1 = figure.add_subplot(121)
ax1.imshow(A)
ax2 = figure.add_subplot(122)
ax2.imshow(B)

plt.show()
```

Here's how the images look like:

[image: A vs B]

Clearly, they are not the same. So, is it just due to different colormaps? If so, for a given application, how do I know a priori which colormap would be used?

Comment: Just after the sentence you quote it says *"This parameter is ignored for RGB(A) data."*. This means normalization and colormapping is only applied to 2D arrays (i.e. shape `(m,n)`), not to images (i.e. shape `(m,n,3)`).

Comment: Further info from [github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9391)